# How to change the watch setting on multiple repositories?

Tags: github

I joined a team that has 100+ repositories on GitHub and the watch default setting is ON. I just need it on a handful of repositories. Is there any way to change this setting for all repos without using the web UI and changing it one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was a few years ago, but thought I'd post in case it helps someone else. I just ran into the same problem and came across this solution. Follow [these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/managing-subscriptions-and-notifications-on-github/managing-subscriptions-for-activity-on-github/managing-your-subscriptions#unwatching-repositories) to Unwatch All, and then go back and re-Watch the handful of repositories you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

In that kind of use case, I would create a second account, and monitor only the few repositories I need from said second account.

That way, I don't have to fiddle with the existing settings for the first account.